# String.Format and TimeSpan issues

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, timespan, string.format

I just started using Unity, and I dont know how to properly debug scripts while working in my code designer VS.

I have this code in a script that wont give me the format i want:

```
private string GetTimeElapsedAsString()
{
    TimeSpan timeElapsed = DateTime.Now.Subtract(_startTime);
    return string.Format("{0:mm} {1:ss} {2:ff}", timeElapsed.TotalMinutes,   timeElapsed.TotalSeconds, timeElapsed.TotalMilliseconds);
}
```

What i want is something like this: "00:07:32" in the given format: "mm:ss:ff"

I just want the easiest way to cut off all but 2 digits of every time unit.
Any Ideas?

Regards Kalrin.

EDIT (Progressed):
I modified the code. Now it looks like this:

```
private string GetTimeElapsedAsString()
{
    TimeSpan timeElapsed = DateTime.Now.Subtract(_startTime);
    return string.Format("{0:00}:{1:00}:{2:00}", timeElapsed.Minutes, timeElapsed.Seconds, timeElapsed.Milliseconds);
}
```

Still when I go to test my game I get 3 digits displaying milliseconds - Why is this happening??

Looks like this:
[UI Text component in Unity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0lYjL.png)

EDIT:
I found a solution to my last issue:

```
return string.Format("{0:00}:{1:00}:{2}", timeElapsed.Minutes, timeElapsed.Seconds, timeElapsed.Milliseconds.ToString().Substring(0,2));
```

All I needed was to create a .Substring(0,2) containing only the 2 first digits of the integer.

Thx for those who tried to help!
Looks nice!!:

[Working Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXPh1.png)

Cheers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're passing three numbers to `Format()`.

Numbers don't recognize ``m`,`s`, or`f`, so they just print literal characters.

You want the format string `00` to pad each number to two digits.

Also, you don't actually want `.Total*`; see the documentation.

Comment: Thanks this works! :)
Can you tell me weather there is a better way to do it?
Also, is there anything I can do in the IFormatProvider to include ":" between every unit?

Comment: You can put `:`s in the string itself.

Comment: Thanks! - Would you take a look at my edit in the post? - Seems i get 3 digits at the last format (the milliseconds).

Comment: @Kalrin: Because you passed it a three digit number.  What do you expect?

Comment: I Expected that this code: {2:00} would cut off every digit after the first two digits?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8  If you want to round or truncate a number, do it yourself using math.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you try

```
 ts.ToString("mm:ss:ff");
```

Comment: Unity may not support that; it was added to a fairly recent framework version.

Comment: I tried this:
return (timeElapsed.Minutes + timeElapsed.Seconds + timeElapsed.Milliseconds).ToString("mm:ss:ff");
- Didn't work - Nothing is passed to the Text component.

Comment: @Kalrin: That format string applies to `TimeSpan`, not numbers.